# How to code to have less time complexity in binary search for a number of queries?

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, time-complexity, binary-search

Problem:

> time limit per test: 1 second
> memory limit per test: 256 megabytes
> input: standard input
> output: standard output
>
> Given 2 numbers **N** and **Q**, array **A** of **N** numbers and **Q** queries each one contains a number **X**.
> For each query, print a single line that contains "found" if the number **X** exists in array **A** otherwise, print "not found".
>
> Input:
>
> First line contains two numbers **N**, **Q** (1 ≤ **N**, **Q** ≤ 10<sup>5</sup>).
>
> Second line contains **N** numbers (1 ≤ **A**<sub>i</sub> ≤ 10<sup>9</sup>).
>
> Next **Q** lines contain **X** (1 ≤ **X** ≤ 10<sup>9</sup>).
>
> Output:
>
> Print the answer for each query in a single line.
>
> Example:
> INPUT
>
> ```
> 5 3
> 1 5 4 3 2
> 5
> 3
> 6
> ```
>
> OUTPUT
>
> ```
> found
> found
> not found
> ```

My Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n, q;
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &q);
    long long int a[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%lld", &a[i]);
        //insertion sort, Ascending order
        int temp;
        for (int j = i; j > 0 && a[j] < a[j - 1]; j--)
        {
            temp = a[j];
            a[j] = a[j - 1];
            a[j - 1] = temp;
        }
    }

    //Binary Search
    long long int x, found = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++)
    {
        scanf("%lld", &x);
        int l = 0, r = n - 1, mid;
        while (l <= r)
        {
            mid = (l + r) / 2;
            if (a[mid] == x)
            {
                found=1;
            }
            if (a[mid] < x)
            {
                l = mid + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                r = mid - 1;
            }
        }
        if (found == 1)
        {
            printf("found\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("not found\n");
        }
        found = 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I tried sorting the array while taking input and used a loop for queries and the binary search. After submission, this code shows `Time limit exceeded on test 2`. I don't know how I can reduce the time complexity of this code. Please help me!

Comment: You should `break` out of the `while` loop when you find the item.

Comment: Why don't you use `qsort()`? And why do you use `long long` when the input limit is 10^9?

Comment: Aside: don't set `found = 0;` at the *end* of the loop. Set it right before you begin each loop.

Comment: Your sort doesn't work. Try printing the array after you've sorted it.

Comment: Your sort is O(n^2). Change to an O(n log n) sort.

Comment: Use functions — don't put all the code in `main()`.

Comment: @WeatherVane OP is doing some codeforces problems and `long long` was required for the summation problem [in a prior question]

Comment: There is an error in the code: `scanf("%d", &a[i]);` should be `scanf("%lld", &a[i]);`. Always test your code locally so that you have access to compiler warnings.

Comment: That’s not an insertion sort. Look it up.

Comment: @user207421 I used the algorithm from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-for-insertion-sort/ and If I am wrong here would you be kind enough to provide me correct name of the sorting I used?

Comment: No you didn't. Compare their code to yours. Completely different. The name for yours is 'bug'.

Comment: You are not sorting the queries.  Divide and conquer rules there too.

Comment: @rcgldr, why do you describe `int` as "_signed 32 bit number_"?  `int` is a signed integer whose range must include [at least -32767 to +32767](https://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A90%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C-27%2C816%2Cnull%5D).  It might be 32 bits on your system, but good code doesn't depend on non-portable assumptions.  That said, `long` _is_ guaranteed large enough to represent ±10⁹.

Comment: @TobySpeight - deleted my prior comment.  Most modern compilers (32 bit or 64 bit) use 32 bit signed integers for `int`. Some compilers use 64 bit signed integers for `long`.

Comment: @Didar004 - if the maximum value for a[] is 10^9, then a signed 32 bit integer is large enough to hold the value.  If sorting, radix sort base 256 would be fastest. As mentioned in chkrlie's answer, you could use 128MB of memory, and set a bit for each value in a[], which is just indexing bits in an array. There's also the potential issue of calling scanf up to 2* 10^5 times to read in the array and the queries in 1 second.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in the complexity of the binary search for each query, it is the complexity of the insertion sort phase, which is quadratic.

You can reduce the complexity by using `qsort` to sort the array (complexity **N.log(N)**),

You could even reduce it to linear as you are given a big hint: *memory limit per test: 256 megabytes*. Therefore, you can use a bit array of length 10<sup>9</sup> which uses 128MB and set the corresponding bit for each number **A<sub>i</sub>** read in and test the bit for each query.  This has linear complexity, albeit with a high factor.

Here is a modified version using `qsort`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int compare_long(const void *aa, const void *bb) {
    const long *a = aa;
    const long *b = bb;
    return (*a > *b) - (*a < *b);
}

int main(void)
{
    int n, q;
    if (scanf("%d %d", &n, &q) != 2)
        return 1;

    // long is enough for |Ai| <= 10**9
    long int *a = calloc(sizeof *a, n);
    if (a == NULL)
        return 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (scanf("%ld", &a[i]) != 1)
            return 1;
    }
    qsort(a, n, sizeof(*a), compare_long);

    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
        long int x;
        if (scanf("%ld", &x) != 1)
            return 1;
        // Binary Search
        int l = 0, r = n;
        while (l < r) {
            int mid = l + (r - l) / 2;
            if (a[mid] <= x) {
                r = mid;
            } else {
                l = mid + 1;
            }
        }
        if (l < n && a[l] == x) {
            printf("found\n");
        } else {
            printf("not found\n");
        }
    }
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

If the time limit is stiil exceeded, you could try and use Radix Sort to sort the array instead of `qsort` or use the bit array as explained above.

Comment: I deleted my prior comment. I'll delete this comment later.